# Remove TFS Bindings without a hack

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, tfs, version-control, source-control-bindings

I have a 2013 Visual Studio Web Project which was in source control. It has been detached for some time and now I want to move it to a completely new TFS server but when I do it errors and complains expecting certain folders to exist. I think this is due to the TFS bindings.

Now I have seen lots of posts about how to edit the solution file to remove the bindings, plus a few other steps but I'm wondering if there is a menu item which you can click to remove the bindings so I can point at a different TFS server? I am hoping I don't need to edit solution file.

I am not simply being lazy - but I want a defacto way of doing this correctly in one go, not hack here and hack there. Hacking a solution file from someone's advice is not the same as clicking a 'Microsoft' menu item.

Comment: Can you post the error messages? Also when you removed the bindings previously did you use "File -> Source Control -> Change Source Control settings" from the Visual Studio menu?

Answer (score 0):

Quite easy, you just need to follow my steps and you will get it worked.

1. Open your solution, for now its under source control with your old
   TFS server.
2. Move to `File -> Source Control -> Change Source Control` , on the
   pop-up window click the **unbind**, you can unbind all of the
   solution or a specific project. Will get a below screenshot.

   [image]
3. You can check the solution in solution explorer, there is no lock
   icon which means not in source control any more.

   [image]
4. However, this isn't over. Since your solution file is still in the
   workspace which associate with the old TFS server. So if you want to
   add the solution to new source control right now, you will get an
   error:

   > " The item 'ConsoleApplication1.sln' is already under source control
   >   at the selected location xxx"....
5. **You have to copy this solution to a different place out of your
   workspace.** And change the connection of TFS  to the new TFS
   server(which you want to add source control with).

   [image]
6. Finally, open the solution from local folder(new copied). Right
   click the solution in solution explorer select "**Add solution to
   source control**" and choose the location you want add to.