# How to simply move a VS2015 Solution to a new project in TFS 2013?

Tags: visual-studio-2015

I have a solution with several projects in it. That solution was saved to our TFS 2013 default collection but under the wrong project. 
I am trying to move/copy it to the proper project in TFS. 
I unbound the solution and projects, closed everything down. Reopened the solution and tried to add it to a new project but it still seems to want to rebind to the old project.

If I create new files they are stored in the correct project but all of the old files are still being committed in the old project locations.

How can this be put into the correct project without starting from scratch with a new solution and projects?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you didn’t completely remove TFS source control Bindings. This is caused by your solution file is still in the workspace which associate with original source control. You can try to copy this solution to a different place out of your original workspace. Detail steps please refer my answer in this question: [Remove TFS Bindings without a hack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36194920/remove-tfs-bindings-without-a-hack/36216586#36216586)

More ways and more information for you reference:[How can I completely remove TFS Bindings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/358951/how-can-i-completely-remove-tfs-bindings). Also try to [clean TFS an VS cache](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/willy-peter_schaub/2010/09/15/if-you-have-problems-with-tfs-or-visual-studio-flush-the-user-cache-or-not/) and try again..